# Docker and Nginx - thoroughly confused at his point

Tags: server, 22.04, docker, nginx, ssl

I'm new to Ubuntu and Docker.  I've installed Ubuntu 22.04 Workstation (basic installation) on a public virtual machine. I can access it via ssh and I have my domain pointed at the server's ip address.

I'm in the process of installing OTOBO Helpdesk.  This is actually my third server attempt as I am trying to make sure I set it up right with notes.

The first time, I installed Nginx, Certbot and got my ssl certificate working. I then installed Docker and the OTOBO container. When I tried to run it on the typical ports 80/443, I was getting the message the they were in use. I figured that Nginx has them in use so I shut down Nginx and then my website stopped working altogether.

Where I am confused is, should I be installing Nginx on the host machine with the ssl certificate or is that done on the container? If I run Nginx on the host machine, it uses the ports that OTOBO wants to use and prevents it from running. I have a conflict with the two running so I'm going to assume I'm setting this up incorrectly.

I got to Part 4 and it says:

> See e.g.
> https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-for-nginx-in-ubuntu-18-04
> on how to create self-signed certificates.

I did the setup for 22.04 and then started up the container, that's when I get the ports in use.
I'm trying to get my domain and ssl certificate to work with the OTOBO instance but it seems that running Nginx at the same time causes issues.

I did everything in the instructions and when I got to this part "Start the Docker containers with Docker Compose", it says that the ports were in use.

Please help this confused fool.